# GCP Proxy to insecure endpoint

Tags: http, google-cloud-platform, reverse-proxy

I would like to send a request (https) to GCP get GCP to route that request to another (http) onsite endpoint

for example

request intiator: https://some.google.domain.com/some-path (contains body headers etc)

GCP receives this request and forward to

http://myonsitedomain.com/some-path (contains body headers etc)

Is there a solution for this or do I have to create a cloud function for this?

Answer (score 1):

External HTTP(S) Load Balancing is a proxy-based Layer 7 load balancer that enables you to run and scale your services behind a single external IP address. External HTTP(S) Load Balancing distributes HTTP and HTTPS traffic to backends hosted on a variety of Google Cloud platforms (such as Compute Engine, Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE), Cloud Storage, and so on), as well as external backends connected over the internet or via hybrid connectivity. Using this external load balancer you can resolve your issue, follow the source link for more information ([source: GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https))